# switching canvas / rendertarget in three.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I have two canvas elements on my page and I start rendering to my:

```
new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:myFirstCanvas});
```

and the 3D scene is properly rendered as I expect

but then if I try to change the canvas element the renderer is pointing to by using either:

```
renderer.domElement = mySecondCanvas;
```

or

```
renderer.setRenderTarget({canvas:mySecondCanvas});
```

I have looked on the documentation on github but setRenderTarget() says TODO unfortunately.
Is it possible to switch the canvas element the renderer is using? and if so how would I go about this? currently my attempt does nothing but blur the image in the original canvas element presumably because I also resize the renderer with:

```
renderer.setSize(mySecondCanvas.width,mySecondCanvas.height);
```

when I'm trying to switch over to the other canvas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, and this is due to hon WebGL work and has nothing to do with Three.js specifics, but each WebGL-context (in Three.js represented by the WebGL renderer) is bound to a canvas element and you cannot change which element the WebGL-context should render to.

So: make two THREE.WebGLRenderers, one for each canvas element.

Comment: BTW: render target is a texture that you render to.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I might have to do that, so do I just swap scene and camera over between renderers to swap the content or can I get away with just swapping the scene. Also should I call renderer1.render(scene1,camera1) and renderer2.render(scene2,camera2) in the same requestAnimationFrame() or should I use two seperate calls to requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: You can use the same requestAnimationLoop callback, no problem. Each WebGL context could be seen as two different chunks of memory that cannot access each other and there might be properties added to the scene/the scene objects/camera object which refer to a specific piece of memory and thus failing. My gut feeling is that the objects in the scene (and therefore the scene itself) is the hardest to reuse, but the camera should be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

this [post](https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-rendertargets.html) was really helpful to me

it looks like you do not have to create an extra canvas nor renderer, but rather an additional renderTarget with it's own scene and camera

Comment: Dead link, web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20220929105714/https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-rendertargets.html